# Laravel - How to update query by transforming existing column value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table of users with column **phone_number**. I want to update the table by keeping the last 9 characters of the existing values.

This is the query I'm using and it doesnt work for me.

`$user = User::where('usertype','=',1)->get();`
`$user->update(['phone_number' => substr($user['phone_number'],-9)]);`

I get the error **"Undefined array key "phone_number"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it on the database without getting the data.

```
$numberOfAffectedRows = User::where('usertype','=',1)->update(['phone_number' => \DB::raw("SUBSTRING('phone_number',-9)")]);
```